# How to save a couple of values that will be read and changed periodically in MVC (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, app-config

I have a web app working with a couple of console worker applications that are responsible for processing large sums of data and emails. The console apps need to read a couple of configuration values edited my the web application. These values will tell the console apps how fast to work per a period of time.

I do not want to use a database to store these 2 values as I would result in a table with a single row of 2 columns. And of course I cannot write them to the web.config as that will result in the web app restarting every time I do.

Can someone suggest a good practice to have these values written and read by multiple apps? maybe a config.xml file or something. Please note that I need to access these values through an action, returning a Json object. So basically I will do:

```
foo.com/controller/getconfig
```

And that will give me back the Json object with what I need through a webclient.

My apologies for the excessive blabbering. And thank you for any help.

Comment: Is the web app and other processes on the same machine?

Comment: No. That is why I need to call it through a URL.

Comment: Then use Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "my-app")); and maintain a file under it